# Merging a string to XML

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, vb6, ixmldomelement

I am actually updating a Legacy application in `VB 6.0` and I need to add an element to a XML declared as `IXMLDOMElement`. 
My XML object's content is actually as follows;

```
<ChoiceLists>
 <Test Default="*">
  <Choice Value="1" Description="Hours"/>
  <Choice Value="2" Description="Days"/>
 </Test>
</ChoiceLists>
```

And now I have a query which is already returning me a XML formatted result (as string), as

```
<Test2 Default="*">
  <Choice Value="276" Description="#276"/>
  <Choice Value="177" Description="#177"/>
  <Choice Value="0000" Description="#0000"/>
  <Choice Value="176" Description="#176"/>
</Test2>
```

which I need to integrate in my XML, that is in the root node `<ChoiceLists>`.

Can anyone tell me how do I add this string into my XML please?
I've been trying the different functions of the `IXMLDOMElement` object but in vain.

Thanks

Comment: Once you have the two bits of XML in a `IXmlDomElement`, you just need to do `element.AppendChild(newChildElement)`.

Comment: for this, `newChildElement` should be of type `IXMLDOMElement`, but mine is in string. I want it to fit in between the root node `<ChoiceLists>`

Comment: How did you load the other XML into a DOM object? It's the same method.

Comment: Initially what was done, is that a new element is created 'createElement' and the attributes are being set. Now since I already have the fully-built xml (but in string format), how do I integrate it in the existing xmlDomElement

Comment: It's normally better to create and pass it around as XML DOM elements rather than strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of the [`IXMLDOMNode.appendChild()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms766535(v=vs.85).aspx) method to add one element (and children) to another element.
If you have a raw string that you need to convert, you can load that into a new `DOMDocument` using [`IXMLDOMDocument.loadXML()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754585(v=vs.85).aspx)

```vb
Dim TargetDocument As IXMLDOMDocument
Dim TargetElement As IXMLDOMElement
Dim NewDocument As IXMLDOMDocument
Dim NewElement As IXMLDOMElement

'Load your target document here
Set TargetDocument = New DOMDocument
TargetDocument.Load "P:\iCatcher Console\XML\feedlist.xml"

'Get a reference to the element we want to append to (I'm assuming it's the document element)
Set TargetElement = TargetDocument.DocumentElement

'Create a new documents to parse the XML string
Set NewDocument = New DOMDocument
NewDocument.loadXML NewXMLString

'The root of this document will be the outer element in the string so get a reference to that
Set NewElement = NewDocument.DocumentElement

'Append the new element to the target's children
TargetElement.appendChild NewElement
```

The resulting XML will now be something like:

```xml
<ChoiceLists>
 <Test Default="*">
  <Choice Value="1" Description="Hours"/>
  <Choice Value="2" Description="Days"/>
 </Test>
 <Test2 Default="*">
  <Choice Value="276" Description="#276"/>
  <Choice Value="177" Description="#177"/>
  <Choice Value="0000" Description="#0000"/>
  <Choice Value="176" Description="#176"/>
 </Test2>
</ChoiceLists>
```

Comment: Error on appending child `TargetElement.appendChild(NewElement)` - `Run-time error '5' - Invalid procedure call or argument` :(

Comment: Sorry, there were a few typos.

Comment: Yet another error: `Run-time error '438' Object doesn't support this property or method.` I guess it's because of the AppendChild, which accept an IXMLDomNode

Comment: It works for me. Double check it's the `TargetElement` you passing it to, not `TargetDocument`.

Comment: It does work using the code I gave. You'll need to show the line that's failing (and the type of the variables used)

Comment: I did almost the same thing, whereby my TargetDocument is the existing XML of type `IXMLDOMElement`. I succeeded in converting my string to `IXMLDOMDocument` as in your proposed solution. Only for the last line `TargetElement.appendChild NewElement` to end with error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61392/discussion-between-deanna-and-nadeem-mk).